# Loading data into DataGridView in C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am trying to add values from Win32_SystemDriver into a `DataGridView`, I it will load until it finishes. When it ends up loading all the data it will change all the rows for the last value from the query. This is the code:

```
ObjectQuery query8 = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_SystemDriver"); 

ManagementObjectSearcher searcher8 = 
    new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query8);

foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher8.Get())
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("Descrição");
    foreach (DataGridViewRow oItem in dataGridView1.Rows)  
    {
        dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { queryObj["Description"] });
    }
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
}
```

What it's wrong about this code? Why after loading every data it will change every row to the last value from the query?

This is how I solve it by myself:

```
ObjectQuery query8 = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_SystemDriver"); 

ManagementObjectSearcher searcher8 = 
    new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query8);

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Descrição");

foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher8.Get())
{
    dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { queryObj["Description"] });
}

dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that at each iteration you create a new `DataTable`, which you populate and assign as `DataSource`. At the next iteration you repeat this process and erase the information from before. Therefore you end up at the last iteration with only the last entry.

Another problem is you inner loop. After assigning the first time `dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;` it will have 1 row, so you can add 1 element to your `DataTable` at the next iteration it will be 2 and so on.

You need to move the declaration of the `DataTable` and the setting of the `DataSource` outside of the outer loop and remove the inner loop

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Descrição");

foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher8.Get())
{    
    dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { queryObj["Description"] });
}
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

Comment: If I do that it displays an error saying: "A column named 'Descrição' already belongs to this DataTable"

Comment: @Rekcs Do you want to have only 1 column for all `ManagementObject` queries ?

Comment: @Rekcs then you should probably move it also outside the loop. I edited my answer

Comment: I want only a column, yes. I've changed with your code and it won't give me any error but does not displays values from ManagementObject

Comment: @Rekcs but it did display them before?

Comment: With my code from the post, it will display everything and after loading it every row will be changed by the last value from the query

Comment: I've solved it see my post if possible. Thank you anyway

Comment: @Rekcs you are welcome, the best way of saying thank you on StackOverflow is to [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) that helped you. As I see you haven't accepted any to all of your questions up to now

Comment: @Rekcs it worked with your former version because after the first assignment of the DataSource you increased the number of rows in your datagridview, so your inner loop worked. which of course does not work when you assign the datasource only at the end